# How to automatically hide and show an element with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6nrjw0Le/7/)

I have a button that when clicked creates an h1 input and starts a progress bar. I want the text to dissapear right before the progress bar fills up and appear when it starts filling again every time it fills up. I've tried jquery hide(), remove(), detach() and empty() but can't find a way to make it be able to do what I want.

```
var auto = 3;
var nb = 0;

var progress = function(sec) {
  var interval = 1000; //milliseconds
  setTimeout(function() {
    sec = sec + 25;
    $('#bar').val(sec);
    if (sec > 100) {
      $('#bar').val(0);
      sec = 0;
      nb++;
    }
    if (nb < auto) 
      progress(sec); //call self with new value
  }, interval)
}

$('#battle').click(function() {
  $('#dam').html("You have hit the " + $('#monsters').val() + " for 5 damage").delay(4500).fadeOut(400);
  progress(0); //initialize progress bar
});
```

Comment: Is that what you want https://jsfiddle.net/6nrjw0Le/10/?

Comment: No I need the text to reappear every time the progress bar reaches 0 and begins to fill again, so in my example it would show up 3 times because the progress bar fills 3 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
var auto = 3;
var nb = 0;

var progress = function(sec) {
  $('#dam').html("You have hit the " + $('#monsters').val() + " for 5 damage").show().delay(4500).fadeOut(400);
  var interval = 1000; //milliseconds 
  setTimeout(function() {     
    sec = sec + 25;
    $('#bar').val(sec);
    if (sec > 100) {
      $('#bar').val(0);
      sec = 0;
      nb++;
    }
    if (nb < auto) progress(sec); //call self with new value
  }, interval)
}

$('#battle').click(function() {  
  progress(0); //initialize progress bar
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

progress {
   appearance: none;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   width: 100%;
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #81ff14;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  color: #81ff14;
}

select {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-color: #81ff14;
  color: #81ff14;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

button {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-color: #81ff14;
  color: #81ff14;
  border-radius: 10%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#dam {
  color: #81ff14;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  max-width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress max="100" value="0" id="bar"></progress>

<select id="monsters">
  <option>Fly</option>
  <option>Mouse</option>
  <option>Rat</option>
  <option>Rabbid Rabbit</option>
  <option>Baby Ent</option>
  <option>Murloc</option>
  <option>Ent</option>
</select>

<button type="button" id="battle">Battle!</button>

<p id="dam">

</p>
```

Comment: Works thanks, I tried something similar but didn't quite have it.

Comment: NP, just needed to show the element at first since you are hiding it after your call it.

Comment: how does this animate only 3 times, since the function gets called 15 times, does it wait until the animation is over to show the new one?

Comment: How do you see this being called 15 times? The progress function is recursive as it calls itself twice after the initial call.